# How do I transfer VHS to digital video?

Tags: video

I've got every generation of Raspberry PI around the house and a VCR with composite output.

What's the simplest setup to digitize old tapes (including buying small equipment)?

CLI preferred, but I'll put up with GUI if I have to :)

Comment: There's no composite input (there's no HDMI input either) on your Raspberry.

Comment: upvote for `I'll put up with GUI if I have to` .... lol

Answer (score 1):

You just need a composite to USB video capture device. These are pretty common. I assumed there are higher speed devices out there but searching for one led to explanations of why that would be very expensive for the way VHS would have to be read at higher speed. Either way, make sure you clean your VHS player.

This is not a recommendation, just the first example I grabbed:
[https://www.amazon.com/Video-Capture-Converter-Adapter-Cable/dp/B071WRC8V6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071WRC8V6)
Finding one that worked with Linux might be a trick, but there are some that go straight to SD cards or something too.

Comment: AFAIK these devices come exclusively with a Windows driver, so there's no way to use that with an RPi.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Good point. That's the reason to ask explicitly for RPi. Though straight to sd card sounds good... Better than CLI -- no interface at all!